# Web Usercontrol menu item dynamic selected style not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web user control,it include menu.It have 4 menu items,I am using Style sheet for Dynamic and static selected style.But Static and dynamic selected style is not working.How to solve this problem

Comment: can you check whether the path you added is correct or not

Comment: Thanku for reply nad,Now my page redirect coding is code behaind in Menu item click,Now my code is work perfectly.

Comment: 2, The codebehind of the menuitemclick event:
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Selected"] = e.Item.Text;
        if (e.Item.Text == "Page1")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/menu/default.aspx");
        }
        else if(e.Item.Text == "Page2")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/menu/default2.aspx");
        }
        else if (e.Item.Text == "Page3")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/menu/default3.aspx");
        }
    }

Comment: You should paste the above code into your `question`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2, The codebehind of the menuitemclick event:

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    Session["Selected"] = e.Item.Text;
    if (e.Item.Text == "Page1")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/menu/default.aspx");
    }
    else if(e.Item.Text == "Page2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/menu/default2.aspx");
    }
    else if (e.Item.Text == "Page3")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/menu/default3.aspx");
    }
}
```

page load on user control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Selected"] != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Menu1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Menu1.Items[i].Text == Session["Selected"].ToString())
            {
                this.Menu1.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```